# Check if username exists in database with codeigniter and ajax

Tags: sql, ajax, codeigniter, activerecord, model

Can anyone help me check if a username is in my database using ajax and code igniter?
I can't use the form_validation method as I have modal windows which interfere with the checking.

Currently my controller looks like:

```
 function filename_exists(){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $data['exists'] = $this->User_model->filename_exists($username);
    }
```

My Model:

```
 function filename_exists($username)
 {

     $this->db->select('*'); 
     $this->db->from('users');
     $this->db->where('username', $username);
     $query = $this->db->get();
     if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 }
```

and my ajax post:

```
function check_if_exists() {

     <?php $username = $this->input->post('username');
    ?>
     var username = '<?php echo $username ?>';
    var DataString=$("#form1").serialize();
     $.ajax({
     url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Files/filename_exists/",
     type: "post",
     data: DataString + '&username=' + username,
     success: function(response) {


            if (response == true) {
                $('#msg').html('<span style="color: green;">'+msg+"</span>");

            }
             else {

                $('#msg').html('<span style="color:red;">Value does not exist</span>');
            }


         }
     });


}
```

UPDATE

```
 <form name = "form1" id = "form1" method ="post"> <!--action="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/Admin/create_user"; ?>"-->
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <label for="userID" class = "labelForm">User ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="userID" name="userID" class = "input2">
    <label for="first_name" class = "labelForm">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" class = "input2">
    <label for="last_name" class = "labelForm">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class = "input2">
    <label for="username" class = "labelForm">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class = "input2" onblur="check_if_exists();">
    <label for="password" class = "labelForm">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class = "input2" onblur="checkPasswords();">
    <label for="passconf" class = "labelForm">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="passconf" name="passconf" class = "input2" onblur="checkPasswords();">
    <label for="email" class = "labelForm">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class = "input2">
  <button type="button"  id = "new_user_submit">Add New User</button>
```

Comment: change `$query->num_rows() == 0` as `$query->num_rows() > 0` and test

Comment: `print_r($username)` in controller and check data is coming

Comment: @Abdulla When i try to print the username nothing comes up , but if i console.log(DataString) in the success part of the ajax post it tells me what I have entered?

Comment: @RejoanulAlam I changed it and no luck unfortunately! :(

Comment: show your form codes

Comment: I have updated the code above @Abdulla , thanks for the help as well!

Comment: @user give me 20 mnts will be back ASAP

Comment: Thank you so much @Abdulla ! I really can't figure it out..

Comment: @user check the answer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**In Ajax**

```
function check_if_exists() {

var username = $("#username").val();

$.ajax(
    {
        type:"post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/files/filename_exists",
        data:{ username:username},
        success:function(response)
        {
            if (response == true) 
            {
                $('#msg').html('<span style="color: green;">'+msg+"</span>");
            }
            else 
            {
                $('#msg').html('<span style="color:red;">Value does not exist</span>');
            }  
        }
    });
}
```

**In Controller**

```
function filename_exists()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $exists = $this->User_model->filename_exists($username);

    $count = count($exists);
    // echo $count 

    if (empty($count)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**In Model**

```
function filename_exists($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately its still not working @Abdulla .. when I console.log(username) I can see the init , but when I write console.log(response) it comes up blank

Comment: I've actually found when I echo($count) in the controller it appears to work ( as in have it just before the if statement). This seems like strange behaviour though as when I take it out it seems to return false regardless of the username existing or not.. Is this okay to use like this? @abdulla really appreciate the help as well!

Comment: Why query the db for all the users data? Here would be a better query that will take less time.

`function filename_exists($username)
{
   $this->db->where('username',$username);
   return $this->db->count_all_results('users');
}

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Sir I get blank response in alert  what should i do?

Comment: In controller instead of return add echo. Ex:  return true should be echo true.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam This is my question can you help sir I have used your answer code for it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884102/check-username-is-unique-or-not-using-ajax-in-codeigniter#42884102

Comment: sir @AbdullaNilam  can you help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884102/check-username-is-unique-or-not-using-ajax-in-codeigniter/42884241?noredirect=1#comment72871254_42884241

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to see if the user already exists, there is no reason to query with the get() function. just do the count_all_results() it will return a number if the user is found, 0 if not.

```
function filename_exists($username) {
  $this->db->where('username', $username);
  return $this->db->count_all_results('users'); 
}
```

All this will do is return a number greater than zero if the username exists in your db.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach with same result

**MODEL**

```
function filename_exists($username) {
   $this->db->select()->from('users')->where('username', $username);
   $query = $this->db->get();

   return $query->first_row('array'); // returns first row if has record in db
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function filename_exists() {
   $username = $this->input->post('username');
   $user = $this->user_modal->filename_exists($username);

   return !empty($user); // not empty returns true else false
}
```

**AJAX**

Inside the `check_if_exists` function.

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/files/filename_exists', { username: $('#username').val() }, function(response) {
    var html = '<span style="color:red;">Value does not exist</span>';
    if (response == true) {
       html = '<span style="color: green;">' + msg + '</span>';
    } 
    $('#msg').html(html);
});
```