# check username is unique or not using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Direct to the point.
I am checking that my entered username exists or not exist in the database. So I have decided to use ajax.

The expected result is like when I enter the username which already exists then the div style get change and error message get appear under it but this is not happing now I don't know why?

I am not familiar with ajax so any syntax missing or any wrong technique you see then you can point it out.

This is my controller Function:

```
function check_userName_exists()
{
    $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name');
    log_message('debug', 'Posted Username by Ajax for Check it exist or not : '. print_r($user_name, TRUE));

    $exists = $this->student_db->check_user_name($user_name);

    log_message('debug', 'Username Exist or not Response array: '. print_r($exists, TRUE));

    $count = count($exists);
    // echo $count 
    log_message('debug', 'Username Exist or not Response Count: '. print_r($count, TRUE));

    if ($count == 1) {
        $data['unique'] = 1;
        print(json_encode($data));
    } else {
        $data['unique'] = 0;
        print(json_encode($data));
    }
}
```

This is my model function:

```
function check_user_name($user_name)
{

    $this->db->select('user_name'); 
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where('user_name', $user_name);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $query_last = $this->db->last_query();
    log_message('debug', 'Find UserName is Unique Or Not Query: '. print_r($query_last, TRUE));
    $result = $query->result_array();
    log_message('debug', 'Find UserName is Unique Or Not Result: '. print_r($result, TRUE));
    return $result;
}
```

This is the Ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_if_exists() {

var user_name = $("#user_name").val();
// console.log(user_name);

$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url: "<?php echo site_url('student/check_userName_exists'); ?>",
  data:{ 'user_name':user_name},
  success:function(response)
  {

    if (response.unique = 1) 
    {
      // alert(success);
      //console.log(response);
      $("#userNameDiv").addClass("has-warning");
      $("#user_name").addClass("form-control-danger");
      $("#userNameErrorMsg").text("This User Name Is Already Takken. Please Try Something Else.");
    }
    else 
    {


      $("#userNameDiv").removeClass("has-warning");
      $("#user_name").removeClass("form-control-danger");      
      $('#userNameErrorMsg').text('');
    }    
  }
});
```

};

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="userNameDiv">                    
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-success" name="user_name" required id="user_name" placeholder="Enter Username" onblur="check_if_exists();">
                <small class="text-help" id="userNameErrorMsg"></small>
              </div>
```

> got blank response in console.

Comment: I get the blank response in the consol

Comment: change `return 1` and `return 0` in your controller to `echo '1'` and `echo '0'`. Controller function in CI does not return the response, it should output it.

Comment: I am losing hope on this question that i ever get the proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller function is always going to return 0. Count returns an integer, you're checking if it's empty... Updated the controller code below to fix that.

Ajax expects a json response not a single value.

In your controller print the return value, don't return it.

```
if ($count > 0) {
    $data['unique'] = 1;
    print(json_encode($data));
} else {
    $data['unique'] = 0;
    print(json_encode($data));
}
```

Then in your ajax function

```
if (response.unique == '1')
```

Comment: Sir @RickCalder Sir i have tried your code and every time response get in to the else part of condition even if i entered the existed username.

Comment: console log response as the first thing in the success block (before the if statement)

Comment: ah, also try removing the quotes around the 1 in the ajax if statement if(response.unique==1) instead?

Comment: get the response in the consol sir but the class did not work. Here I add danger class if user name is exist but it didnot show any effect on that div

Comment: See edit, your controller code was checking to see if $count was empty. It won't ever be empty, count() returns an integer so if there is no result it will be 0 not empty

Comment: And see edit again, I got your variables reversed. Sorry

Comment: Sir i Chacked my log and it show that if i enter the existed username then the count goes 1 and if enter any none existed username the count show 0. No the problem is just i did not get the effect which i want like it enter none unique username it show me dangr class in that div but it show nothing.

Comment: 1. Are you sure the ID of the div you're trying to affect is right in the ajax success block? 2. Change JQuery.ajax to $.ajax, don't mix syntax like that. 3. Are you sure the class is not applying? Maybe it is just the css that isn't working?

Comment: Replace your ajax function with this, tell me what your console outputs https://gist.github.com/calder12/36c34f6c99f4f216a16812d81ae19678

Comment: If i Entered the existed username the the consol is:  {"unique":1} 
and when i enter the unique usename then the console is : {"unique":0}

Comment: I have applied your ajax code from GitHub but every time i enter that it show the same console log : User does not exist                                                                  Even if i entered the unique username.

Answer (score 0):

return won't work here, just echo your response instead

```
if (empty($count)) {
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo '0';
}
```

also check whatever response from server

```
success:function(response)
{
   console.log(response); // at beginning  

   // your code

 }
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I just not get the effect on the div while entering   a non-unique username.